# install ROS Kinetic to Mac following ROS tutorial

Tags: macos, wxpython, ros

I am trying to install ROS Kinetic to Mac(macOS Sierra) and ran into two questions:

**Q1. Do I install the ROS into a workspace?**

According to the tutorial:http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source, the installation of the ROS will be done inside a catkin workspace. Did I misunderstood? :
Create a catkin Workspace

In order to build the core packages, you will need a catkin workspace. Create one now:

$ mkdir ~/ros_catkin_ws
$ cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
Next we will want to fetch the core packages so we can build them. We will use wstool for this. Select the wstool command for the particular variant you want to install:

Desktop-Full Install: ROS, rqt, rviz, robot-generic libraries, 2D/3D simulators, navigation and 2D/3D perception

$ rosinstall_generator desktop_full --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init -j8 src kinetic-desktop-full-wet.rosinstall

So I did follow this but then for the later step, it warned me of the lack of some tools which are installed outside of the workspace from the tutorial perviously.

**Q2. I didn't follow the installation of the ROS desktop version to set inside a catkin workspace but under the root directory, everything was going fine until the command:**

$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y

I got this error:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:

actionlib: No definition of [python-wxtools] for OS [osx]

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of wxPython does ROS require?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. I installed wxmac and wxpython even separately but none of these installation can make that error disappear.

Comment: If this is using RIDE underneath, then it looks like wxPython 2.6.12.1 is the ONLY supported version it will work with - https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Installation-Instructions

Comment: I followed another tutorial and successfully install ROS to Mac. so far my wxpython is pip show WxPython
Name: wxPython
Version: 3.0.2.0

Comment: I don't know deal with this error and tried another tutorial to install ROS lunar to Mac: https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx

Comment: im getting the exact same error now

Answer (score 1):

Just managed to get `rosdep install` to run by adding the --skip-keys argument so the command becomes:

`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --skip-keys python-wxtools --rosdistro kinetic -y`

Note: If it turns out at some point that you do not have the wx package, install it with:

`sudo -H python2 -m pip install wxPython`